# Two sentences with a comma and no conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, comma-splices

The [SK Telecom article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SK_Telecom) at Wikipedia says

> SK Telecom is South Korea's largest wireless carrier, it leads the local market with 50.5 percent share as of 2008.

But can it be written like this? The sentence after the comma has a verb but not a conjunction. Why were both sentences written without conjucntion?

I was taught that a comma can join sentences, but not sentences that have two or more verbs without a conjunction. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I edited your question to make it more readable and more conformant with our site standards, but if I have misinterpreted anything in your question, please do not hesitate to roll back. That said, this question is somewhat elementary for this site, which is oriented to advanced users of English. Try a web search on *comma splice*, for example. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also interest you.

Answer (score 2):

The comma in your example is wrong. There are two complete sentences there with no *and* joining them. It is a comma splice and should be replaced with a semicolon or full stop.

> SK Telecom is South Korea's largest wireless carrier; it leads the
>   local market with 50.5 percent share as of 2008.
>
> SK Telecom is South Korea's largest wireless carrier. It leads the
>   local market with 50.5 percent share as of 2008.

Alternatively, you can write

> SK Telecom is South Korea's largest wireless carrier, leading the
>   local market with 50.5 percent share as of 2008.